# Determining if factorization function is onto

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Here's a question from my math textbook:

> Let $D$ be the set of all finite subsets of positive integers, and
>   define $T : \mathbb{Z}^+ \to D$ by the rule: For all integers $n$,
>   $$T (n) = \text{the set of all of the positive divisors of }n.$$
>   a. Is $T$ one-to-one? Prove or give a counterexample.
>   b. Is $T$ onto? Prove or give a counterexample.

The answer in the back claims that $T$ is neither one-to-one nor onto.  Onto is obvious, but how could $T$ not be one-to-one?  No two numbers have the same factorization.  Is this a book error?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct: $T$ is one-to-one. In fact, since $\max T(n)=n$, we see that $\max$ is a left inverse of $T$.

Answer (score 0):

$T$ is not onto because sets of divisors form a lattice under divisibility and not all finite subsets of $\mathbb N$ are lattices.

Comment: Or one could just observe that any subset not containing $1$ is not in the image.